# Cómo hacer que esta función se ejecute cada 2 minutos?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estoy tratando de ejecutar la siguiente funcion cada 2 minutos sin embargo no se ejecuta , alguien tiene alguna observacion sobre si lo estoy haciendo bien o que debe estar mal.

```
 function b(){
    cron(); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
    function cron(b) {
    var screen = $('#loading-screen');
configureLoadingScreen(screen);
    $.ajax({  
      type : 'POST',
      url  : 'Auxiliab.php',

      success :  function(b) {

        location.reload();

      } 
    });

  } 
  setInterval(function(b) {
        cron(b);
    }, 120000); // Lanzará la petición cada 2 minutos
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema es que tienes tu setInterval dentro de la function b, necesitas que esté externamente para que la pueda llamar, o por ende llamar la función primero y ya en ella misma se ejecuta de nuevo.
Intenta esto:

```
function b(){
cron(b); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
function cron(b) {
    var screen = $('#loading-screen');
    configureLoadingScreen(screen);
    $.ajax({  
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'Auxiliab.php',

    success :  function(b) {
        location.reload();
    } 
  });
 }
}

setInterval(b, 120000); // Lanzará la petición cada 2 minutos
```

---

Por otro lado estabas ejecutando mal el llamado a la otra función.

```
setInterval(function(b) {
    cron(b);
}, 120000); // Lanzará la petición cada 2 minutos
```

La manera correcta de hacerlo [según esta guía](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) es así:

```
setInterval(b, 120000);
```

Y al momento de ejecutarse, después de la función llamada, esta cron() así que no debía ir en setInterval.

---

También veo acá que intentas pasar "b" a cron, cron(b).
Pero ten presente que en tu función principal no estás recibiendo nada como parámetro, por ende cron(b) no se ejecutara ya que "b" no existe, y no lo estas pasando a la function b().

---

Espero y sea de ayuda la respuesta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias , tenias razon el setInterval(b, 120000); estaba mal y dentro de la funcion ahora corre sin problema. :D

Comment: Con gusto bro :)